# No CSS o que são propriedades ou atributos Implícitos ou Explicitos? Qual a diferença entre um "Grid Implícito" e um "Grid Explicito"?

Tags: css, html5, css3, layout-responsivo, grid-layout

Tenho escutado basante sobre ***CSS Grid Layout*** https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

O ***Grid Layout*** é construído a partir do `display:grid`, e tenho escutado recorrentemente o termo "Grid Implícito" e "Grid Explicito", porém não entendi direito esse conceito...

- O que seria um *Grid Explícito*? E o que seria um *Grid Implícito*?
- Esse conceito de explícito e implícito também é comum em outras propriedades do CSS?

Comment: Muito boa a pergunta, diga-se de passagem.

Comment: @Sam como dizem que o futuro do layout web é o Grid, então resolvi perguntar rss, esse conceite de explícito e implícito é bem interessante, principalmente quando se usa com `minmax` junto nas colunas. É até possível conseguir layouts bem responsivos mesmo sem os `@media`

Comment: Com certeza. É um assunto digno a ser bastante explorado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Grid Explícito** é quando você define *explicitamente* no seu CSS o número de colunas e linhas de um grid.

**Exemplo:**

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 60px 60px 60px;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

Acima foi definido 3 colunas (`100px 100px 100px`) por 3 linhas (`60px 60px 60px`). Ou seja, se o HTML do grid tiver apenas 9 itens (3x3), irá observar estritamente o que foi definido no CSS:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 60px 60px 60px;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

Agora, definido o grid 3x3 acima, se você acrescentar mais itens (células) no grid, aí entra o **Grid Implícito**, onde o navegador automaticamente insere os itens extras no grid implícito baseando-se no que foi definido pelo grid explícito:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 60px 60px 60px;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">11</div>
    <div class="item">12</div>
</div>
```

Veja que as células 10, 11 e 12 não fazem parte do grid explícito, mas do grid implícito (não faz parte do que foi definido originalmente pelo CSS). O navegador tentou adaptá-las no grid criado, mas ele não sabe a altura que essas células deveriam ter (ele só considera a largura da coluna). Para resolver isso você usa a propriedade `grid-auto-rows` para que o navegador saiba que, quando houver itens extras não definidos no grid explícito, a altura desses itens sejam igual aos demais:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 60px 60px 60px;
    grid-auto-rows: 60px;
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.item{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">11</div>
    <div class="item">12</div>
</div>
```

> Esse conceito de explícito e implícito também é comum em outras
>   propriedades do CSS?

Sim. Em algumas propriedades, quando você não a define de forma explícita no CSS, o navegador aplica o seu padrão (implícito). Por exemplo, no caso da margem do `body`, se você não explicitar a sua margem, será aplicada pelo navegador uma margem de `8px`.

Comment: Ótima explicação, muito obrigado!

Comment: Valeu meu jovem. Tmj.